# Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined sequelize express JS and req.body is an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm having trouble taking the data from the table and creating an API. The table isn't empty but req.body is and it says Vehicle is undefined ? The exact Error message I get is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined" and the req.body response is an empty object.

Please help, I've tried everything.

Model:

```js
import { Model } from 'sequelize';

const PROTECTED_ATTRIBUTES = ['password'];

export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Vehicles extends Model {
    toJSON() {
      // hide protected fields
      const attributes = { ...this.get() };
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
      for (const a of PROTECTED_ATTRIBUTES) {
        delete attributes[a];
      }
      return attributes;
    }
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(vehicles) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  
  Vehicles.init({
    // id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    make: DataTypes.STRING,
    model: DataTypes.STRING,
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Vehicles',
  });
  return Vehicles;
};
```

Models/index.js:

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import enVariables from '../config/config.json';

const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = enVariables[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js'))
  .forEach(file => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line global-require,import/no-dynamic-require
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file)).default(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

export default db;
```

Index.js:

```js
const express = require('express');
const models = require('./src/models');
const Vehicles = models.Vehicles;
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello, please go to /vehicles !')
})

app.get('/vehicles', jsonParser, async function(req ,res){
  // res.send('page under construction')
  // console.log(Vehicles.findOne())
  Vehicles.findAll().then(users => {
    return users
});
});

const port = 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('App is now running at port ', port)
})
```

Comment: Isn't the body usually empty for `get` requests? It may help to explain what and how is data is being sent from the front end.  Separately, passsing `get` requests through middleware returned by `bodyParser.json()` _twice_ (once in `app.use` and again in the `app.get` middleware arguments) seems a little strange and may need looking into.

Comment: you're correct, however it still doesn't explain why Vehicles is undefined when there is data in the table. I'm not quite sure why the information isn't coming across and I think I just thought it was linked to the req.body.

Answer (score 1):

Issue has been solved, it is because I was using `EcmaScript` modules (`export`, `import`) in `models/index.js`, then importing it using `CommonJS` (`module.exports`, `require`) in index.js. That caused issues. I should have used the same module format on both sides, or `console.log` what `require('./src/models')` outputs to debug it.

I changed:

```
const models = require('./src/models')
```

To:

```
const models = require('./src/models').default;
```

but I ideally should only use one module format